# SharePoint Search - Force pdf to open in Adobe

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, sharepoint-search

We're replacing our old Google Search Appliance with SharePoint Search and the one difference I noticed is that the GSA will open `.pdf` files in Adobe, but SharePoint opens them in-browser.  I thought this was an Adobe setting, but the fact that these two open `.pdf` files differently would suggest otherwise.

My question is:  is there a way to set up SharePoint to open `.pdf` in Adobe rather than in-browser?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the **client Intergration** feature.

1. In SharePoint Central Administration site, click Application Management->Manage Web Applications, select the web application for the site.
2. Click Authentication Providers, select default zone, and select Yes for "Enable Client Integration?"

read more over here:

[Configure SharePoint Server to Open Office Documents in Client Application by Default](http://blogs.technet.com/b/officeasia/archive/2013/01/09/configure-sharepoint-server-to-open-office-documents-in-client-application-by-default.aspx)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/b6df4273-4769-4179-a831-ae5504b28f35/opening-pdfs-in-acrobat-9-pro-from-sharepoint-2013

Comment: This has already been enabled.

Comment: did you check the changing the xml file option in blog?

Comment: what is the browser you are using. it also depends on the browsers.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE, what file should I look for in regards to pdfs?  This only references office documents.

Comment: @kesava, Internet Explorer 9 - 11.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information,

Acrobat changes w.r.to browser also needs to be changed other than SharePoint, Please follow the below [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html)

This includes enabled and disabling the adobe ad-on which will enforce the pdf documents to open with a specific program.