# Is it possible to open a pdf-document in sharepoint with a desktop app that supports pdf?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have customize a setting in the document library in Sharepoint, that when a user opens a Word or Excel document, Sharepoint automatically uses the desktop app to open the document instead of the browser.
Can this be done with PDF-documents?

Greetings,

P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to open the pdf from a client program, we need to verify a couple of things, so let's check one by one and after each section checking, verify whether pdf is getting opened from the client program.

**Section: Verify internet explorer settings:**

Follow the below steps from your Internet Explorer :

1. Open Internet Explorer, and choose **Tools > Manage Add-ons.**
2. Under Add-on Types, select **Toolbars and Extensions.**
3. In the Show menu, select **All Add-ons.**
4. In the list of add-ons, select **Adobe PDF Reader.**
5. Click the Enable or Disable button (it toggles depending on the status of the selected add-on):

Enable sets the Adobe PDF Reader add-on to open PDFs in the browser.

**Disable turns off** the add-on so it does not open PDFs in the browser.

For details steps please refer the below article :

[Display PDF in browser | Acrobat, Acrobat Reader](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html)

**Section: Verify the setting from Central Administration:**

And also verify the below setting from SharePoint central administration :

1. In the SharePoint Central Administration site, click **Application Management**->**Manage Web Applications**, select the web application for the site.
2. Click **Authentication Providers**, select default zone, and select Yes for "**Enable Client Integration?**"

Similar thread is discussed here :

[SharePoint Search - Force pdf to open in Adobe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142279/sharepoint-search-force-pdf-to-open-in-adobe)

**Section: Verify the site collection feature and document library settings:**

- Need to activate the **Open Documents in Client Applications default** feature from the site collection settings page.
- Go to the document library advanced settings page, from there, 
  under the section called Opening Documents in the Browser you need to switch from “Open in the browser” to **Open in the client application.**